# Are there better option for a smaller file size than .aiff to be used with AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compression, avaudioplayer, aiff

I'm using AVAudioPlayer to play a short one or two syllables word in my app.  Currently there are 250 .aiff files and each of the file is roughly 88KB to 125KB each.  Currently my ipa file is at 29Megs and I am trying to find the best way to reduce the size so user don't have to have a wifi to download it.

Each of the sound clip is 1 to 2.5 seconds long.  I don't need to pause, rewind, fast forward etc.

Based on what I read so far AVAudioPlayer only play aiff, wav or caf and none of those are compressed.  Any recommendation on what I can do?  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CAF files can be compressed, using either lossy or lossless algorithms. If you're using the command line `afconvert` utility to convert, you could try:

- afconvert -f caff -d ima4 audiofile.wav (for IMA4 compression)
- afconvert -f caff -d aac audiofile.wav (for AAC compression)

There's also a -b parameter that allows you to set the output bit rate, and a bunch of other options. The man page is basically empty but the full array of possibilities are listed in [QA1534](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1534/_index.html).

Comment: I didn't end up doing this and ended up converting it into m4a.  I didn't realize that AVAudioPlayer worked with m4a.   But thank you.

Comment: I didn't realise that either. But both CAF and M4A can end up carrying exactly the same logical content (and probably have a related structure, but don't quote me on that) so it's not surprising. I'm glad you solved your problem!

Comment: just an fyi but you probably already know this. the conversion from aiff to m4a yielded about 75% compression.  My files went from 88KB to 21KB  so i was able to convert all sound from 23MB to 6MB and now my IPA file is only 15MB